# How to close a nativescript modal after a few navigations?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

A modal is opened, which has multiple pages. For the navigation I'm using frame navigation. There is a close button on every page clicking on which closes the modal.

What I'm doing now is passing `this.$modal` as a property to each page which creates a long chain of property passing and on each page I just do `this.modal.close()` where `this.modal` is the property of the component that refers to the `this.$modal` of the first page.

I was wondering if there was a better way, such as accessing the topmost open modal and closing it.

I'm using `nativescript-vue` and the builtin nativescript [modals](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/#modal-view-navigation)

Please note that I have multiple modals in other parts of my application. there is only this one that has navigation in it.

Comment: Is this.$modal already globally registered object?

Comment: @Dev.DY no. within every modal's main component. this.$modal exists.

Comment: You have proposed a solution to use by registering $modal global. Please check your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small improvement could be saving the modal into the Vuex store, accessing it anytime instead of chaining props.

Comment: I believe this is a bad smell since the modal reference is not really a 'state' or data. I don't think it belongs to vuex.

Comment: It necessarily need not to be data, more of a global reference, may be a better choice if you are already using Vuex. Or you could use a EventBus.

Comment: @Manoj I've heard vuex to be the place for the global state, not the global reference.

Comment: It's my opinion, it's doesn't hurt to store a reference there and clear it later, than passing it via long props chain. Also the alternative could be EventBus to trigger global event and handle close action.

Answer (score 1):

1. Detach modal component by plugin.

```
const modalDialog = {
  install (Vue, options = {}) {
     // ...
  }
}

Vue.use(modalDialog)
```

3. Designate Vue prototype for plugin.

```
const modalDialog = {
  install (Vue, options = {}) {
     Vue.prototype.$modal = {
       show () {
         // ...
       },
       hide () {
         // ..
       }
     }
  }
}

Vue.use(modalDialog)
```

4. `this.$modal` is accessible from all components.

```
this.$modal.show() // or hide()
```

Comment: As good as this answer is, it does not exactly fit within the context of nativescript modals. I'm sorry, I guess I should have made things more clear  in my question. I will now.